# Accelerometer/gyroscope not used by apps LG L70

Tags: cyanogenmod, lg, gyroscope

When I tried to watch a 360 youtube video, I noticed I couldn't look around using my accelerometer. So I installed an app to debug accelerometer information, and it seemed to work just fine.

I do have a custom rom (unofficial cyanogenmod 12.1) on my LG L70 but this was also a problem with the stock LG rom.

Any tips on fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

The L70 doesn't have a gyroscope.

Comment: Note that it MAY be possible in a rooted device to emulate a gyroscope in software on devices that do not have a real one... I know it works on the Honor 5x and I plan on trying it on a Moto G 2015 this evening... http://forum.xda-developers.com/honor-5x/how-to/tutorial-enable-gyroscope-honor-5x-t3322256